# How to re-position an iTextSharp ColumnText after testing with Go(True)?

Tags: vb.net, pdf-generation, itext

I'm writing a little wrapper for ColumnText which handles vertical alignment - ie. top/middle/bottom-aligned within the bounding box.

When I call `SetSimpleColumn`, it requires the position of the bounding box. Calling `Go(True)` (true = test mode) allows me to test how tall the text will be. From there, I want to re-assign the Y-coordinate, so the text is shown at the desired new position when I call `Go()`. If possible, how is it done?

Ed: Example:

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
...

columnText = New pdf.ColumnText(pageContentByte)
columnText.SetSimpleColumn(New Phrase("some text"), x1, y1, x2, y2, leading)
columnText.Go(True) ' Test mode.'
y1 = y2 + (y1 - columnText.yLine) ' Bottom-align it.'
''
' HOWTO: Re-position Y-coordinate (y1) of columnText object?'
''
columnText.Go()     ' Render at adjusted Y position.'
```

<sup>(single quotes added to end of comments to make syntax highlighting work properly)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The variables that `SetSimpleColumn()` sets are protected so you can't access them directly. However, you should just be able to re-use the `SetSimpleColumn()` method with your updated parameters.

```
columnText.SetSimpleColumn(New Phrase("some text"), x1, y1, x2, y2, leading)
columnText.Go(True) ''//Test mode.

y1 = y2 + (y1 - columnText.yLine) ''// Bottom-align it.

columnText.SetSimpleColumn(New Phrase("some text"), x1, y1, x2, y2, leading)
columnText.Go(False) ''// Render at adjusted Y position.
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing that, but wondered if there was a "neater" way that wouldn't involve repeating main code. Tried a custom "MyColumnText" class, overriding Go() but, no matter what protected member I tweaked, it didn't seem to affect anything.